# keyframe,animation のパラメーターをinputtypeから設定したい

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Boxの横幅を　0％50pxから入力した値に変化させるというアニメーションを作成したいのですが
取得した入力値をkeyframeのパラメーターをして設定する方法がわかりません。

こちらがHTMLです。

```
<dl>
<dt>0%</dt><dd>50px</dd>
<dt>100%</dt><dd><input type="text" name="w100" id="w100" size="5">px</dd>
</dl>
<input type="button" value="Set" onclick="set();">
</form>
<div class="box"></div>
```

書きかけのjqueryです。取得した値をkeyframeの100%のwidthにどのように入れいればよいのかご教授ください。

```
function set(){
var a=$("#w100").val();         //valueの取得
var b=a+"px";                   //単位をつける        
$("div").addClass("c"); 
}
```

下記のCSSは入力値が200をしたときのものです。

```
<style>
.box{   margin:10px; padding:0;  height:50px; background:#fcc;
animation-name:anim;
animation-duration:3s;
animation-timin-function:ease-in;
animation-delay:1s;
animation-fill-mode:both;
-webkit-animation:a 3s ease-in 1s both;
}
.c{
@keyframes anim {
         0%     {height:50px; width:50px; } 
         100%   {height:50px; width:200px; }
} 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.KeyFrames](https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes)プラグインの`$.keyframe.define()`とのメソッドで、下記のようにkeyframeのパラメーターを定義できます。

※下の「スニペットを実行」とのボタンをクリックしたら、結果も確認できます。

```js
function set() {
  var width = $("#w100").val();
  var animationName = 'anim_' + width;

  $.keyframe.define([{
    name: animationName,
    '0%': {
      'height': '50px',
      'width': '50px'
    },
    '100%': {
      'height': '50px',
      'width': width + 'px'
    }
  }]);
  
  $(".box").playKeyframe({
    name: animationName,
    duration: '3s',
    timingFunction: 'ease-in',
    delay: '1s',
    fillMode: 'both'
});
}
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes/master/jquery.keyframes.min.js"></script>
<dl>
  <dt>0%</dt>
  <dd>50px</dd>
  <dt>100%</dt>
  <dd>
    <input type="text" name="w100" id="w100" size="5" value="400">px</dd>
</dl>
<input type="button" value="Set" onclick="set();">
</form>
<div class="box"></div>
```